# Why is my Sketch-app slice 1 size unit bigger than its contents?

Tags: sketch-app

I've made an icon which is 47 units wide. It has a border that is 3 units wide so I assume that the total is 50 units wide. Is my assumption wrong?

However, when I create a slice, the slice becomes 51 units wide.
Why is that, and how can I make sure my slice is as big as its contents?

Comment: Both of those measurements seem wrong to me.  I was expecting 53 units.  3 + 47 + 3, since your border would be on both sides of the icon (I assume it is, anyway?).

Comment: I guess he used 3px centered border, which would give him 50px, provided the graphic is aligned to the pixel grid.

Comment: @SpasimirDinev yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a rectangle of 47 and give it a centered border of 3, you're going to get your overall shape out of the pixel grid, consequently taking up more than 50px
[image: misaligned]

You have two options:
1. align the rectangle to subpixels (if it was at 100, 100 position, make it at 100.5, 100.5 position), so it aligns back to the pixel grid
[image: realign]

2. create your icon at 50x50px and set the stroke to inner. make sure it's aligned to pixel grid. export.

Comment: I went for option 1 since this icon was a variation of another one (without a border) so it was easier to fix the alignment then to fix the border position. Thanks. (The issues was fixed quite a while ago, I just forgot to answer it.)

Answer (score 0):

Select your icon and change it's outline position to center then export it.
It'll be exactly the size you are looking for.
[image]

Comment: This is not correct. Make a rectangle, with a border of thickness 1. Compare the export results when you set the border to be `inner` or `center`. The `inner` will have the same size as the rectangle. With `center` the exported rectangle will actually be larger.

Comment: @Anton in the screen shot above I've made size of rectangle to `56x56` and made it's border thickness to `4` with position `center`. When I exported it to PNG `1x` it was the exact `60x60` size.